# Slider pro for React project

Tags: jquery, reactjs

[Slider pro](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro)

I want to use Slider pro on my React application.
I installed but I could not import

Any solutions?

I did it like this:

1. npm install slider-pro(I also installed jquery)
2. Import slider-pro on Component like above

```
    import React from 'react'
    import $ from 'jquery'
    import 'slider-pro/dist/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js' //from node_nodules?

    export default class Home extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount(){
         console.log($("#my-slider")) // ok!
         $("#my-slider").sliderPro() // error: sliderPro is not function
      }
      render(){
         return(
            <div class="slider-pro" id="my-slider">
              <div class="sp-slides">
                <!-- Slide 1 -->
                <div class="sp-slide">
                  <img class="sp-image" src="path/to/image1.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <!-- Slide 2 -->
                <div class="sp-slide">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Slide 3 -->
                <div class="sp-slide">
                    <h3 class="sp-layer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                    <p class="sp-layer">consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
         )
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't think it is a good idea to use jQuery or any jQuery plugin in React at all. There are a lot of alternatives which are build specifically for React which are plug and play.

The problem with using both is that there is an overlap in what they do. React assumes that nothing else is modifying the DOM, which can have unexpected results.

Try looking into alternatives first (For example: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-slider).